# ExpressionEngine 2.3.1 and PHP 5.6 support

Tags: upgrade, database-error

My service provider have upgrading from PHP 5.4 to PHP 5.6.
I'm currently running EE 2.3.1.

After the upgrade, I get a "ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED" on frontend.
In the backend, I can log in, but none of the menuitems work and I get some mysql errors.

As far as I can see, the mysql_escape_string() is used, but is deprecated in PHP 5.6

The errors in backend:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/r769zkuf8qnphvz/Screenshot%202016-03-04%2010.29.35.png?dl=0

First of all, can I upgrade to another version or am I stuck in this version? If so, which possibilities are there, to get the site up and running again?

Comment: If your host is decent, you should be able to change your php version back.

Comment: Perhaps you anyway should consider just to upgrade your EE-install to the latest 2.x-version. 2.3.1 is 4.5 years old now.

Answer (score 1):

A couple things. Usually get the the ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED error when there are PHP errors/notices breaking the gzip output. You can turn off Gzip Output in the Output and Debugging preferences. This will allow you to see what the errors are on the front end.

The errors are most likely strict and deprecation notices. If so, you can disable these error types in your PHP settings (PHP.ini or your host can help you).

```
error_report = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
```